# Leaves on banana plants withering away

Tags: plant-health, containers, banana

My banana plant is withering away. Leaves are starting to turn yellow/brown, droop, and in general the plant is deteriorating. The plant is in a pot, inside, and gets a lot of light although not a lot of direct sunlight. I think this could be some sort of a mineral deficiency but I am not sure. Attached some photos. Any idea?

[image: Plant photo]
[image: Close-up]
[image: Even closer up]

Underside:

[image: Underside image]

Some sort of tiny insects on some leaves:

[image: insect1]
[image: insect2]
[image: insect3]

Comment: can you add a picture of the underside of the leaf where insects like to live?

Comment: I've added one pic, see above. I do see some tiny insects one one or two of the leaves. I will try to photograph them later and add them.

Comment: I have now also added the insect pics. I am not sure if they are causing the damage or they are just hanging out. There are a few of them, I can not observe a large infestation.

Comment: Banana is a short life plant . It produces fruit once and dies sending up multiple new plants.  It may be getting old.

Comment: I understand but it's a young plant that hasn't borne fruit yet.

Comment: is the side facing away from the window yellower? They want hours of full sun a day...